# How to disable uglify-js optimization which removes quotes around object literals?

Tags: javascript, optimization, uglifyjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I have this (legacy) code:

```
var object = {
  'in': 'someThing'
};
```

After `uglify-js` optimization code looks like:

```
var object = {
  in: 'someThing'
};
```

Here is lines from uglify-js readme (features list):

> various small optimizations that may lead to faster code but certainly
>   lead to smaller code. Where possible, we do the following:
>
> foo[“bar”] => foo.bar

How to disable this optimisation? It ruins the application in IE8STD.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Documentation of UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS#usage), you could use this option:

> `-ns` or `--no-squeeze` — don’t call `ast_squeeze()` (which does various optimizations that result in smaller, less readable code).

Comment: Hm. Probably this will help (my bad english..... argh!) Do you want how exactly how I have to use no-squeeze option? I got this. In both cases I got `in` without quotes in a result: https://i.gyazo.com/f7312243868ef6f33c5817862eba76c0.png

Comment: I tried. It doesn't help :( It doesn't even work. If i use -ns without option uglifyjs do nothing (just freezing right after start). Actually I am using `grunt-contrib-uglifyjs`. I found `screwIE8` option. I set it to false and got expected result. Quotes around `in` still exists.

Comment: sorry, i can not help further.

Answer (score 1):

Flag `--screw-ie8` is the solution. Check out the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js).